# Which geo-format does this data represent

Tags: file-formats

I would like to know which file format a website is using. The data is not in lat,long format.

If I do an Inspect element on browser, I get the following data:

```
stroke:rgba (255,7, 58, 0.125);
fill: none;
stroke-width:2;
d: path("M405.556 215.263 L 401.164 212.26 L 399.322 212.734 L 398.472 214.378 M 394.008 231.58 L 391.848 225.337 L 392.662 222.717 L 393.831 222.97 L 393.938 222.307 L 395 221.991 L 395.142 219.686 L 396.453 ")
```

Comment: Looks like scaleable vector graphics (SVG) to me.

Answer (score 3):

This is an SVG path:

```
d: path("M405.556 215.263 L 401.164 212.26 L 399.322 212.734 L 398.472 214.378 M 394.008 231.58 L 391.848 225.337 L 392.662 222.717 L 393.831 222.97 L 393.938 222.307 L 395 221.991 L 395.142 219.686 L 396.453 ")
```

see https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_path.asp for what the bits mean.

Its unlikely the numbers are any sort of geographic reference, they are more likely to be some sort of graphic units (pixels, points, cm) from the bottom left of the SVG drawing object.

If you can extract all the path information *and* you know enough ground truth location of some of the features *and* you can work out the projection of the path *then* you might be able to georeference the SVG path. But its often more efficient to get the data another way.

Comment: Appreciate your detailed solution. Your answer was very PRECISE. I extracted the path info and was able to create the map from the data.